# How to display toolbar icons inside an inflated view toolbar android java

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I have an inflated view in my activity file and the layout file happens to have a Toolbar widget that I desire to fill up with icons. I have tried to use the code `toolbar.Inflate(int resource);` but it is not showing up, the toolbar text is also not showing up with `toolbar.Title=name;`
The code for the layout is this one...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_background"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

     </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <EditText
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="9dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/tinted_camera"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/emoji"
        android:hint="Type a Message"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:id="@+id/message_box"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to inflate the View first, got the ID of my toolbar and tried to inflate the icons to the right of the toolbar as follows but its not working.

```
            try
            {
                //Inflate our view with the Chat layout
                View chat_view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.chat_view, null);
                //define the toolbar
                AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = chat_view.FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar3);
                SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                //get the nanme of the current contact
                string name = (string)contact_list.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
                toolbar.Title= name;
                //inflate this toolbar
                toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.video_menu_item);
                toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.call_menu_item);
                toolbar.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.bars_menu_item);
                toolbar.SetNavigationIcon(Resource.Drawable.back_arrow);
                //build a new alert dialog
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeMaterialLightNoActionBarFullscreen);
                builder.SetView(Resource.Layout.chat_view);
                builder.Show();
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this,ex.Message,ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
```

How do I succeSsfully make this Toolbar in an inflated view to show up the icons and the text?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:menu="@menu/your_menu"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/your_icon" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

I think you need to check your menu.xml file.

Comment: I have more than one menu icons so will assigning only one in the layout file work? Because i believe each menu item can only have one icon drawable

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus here some help

Comment: You did it, now I understand, can you show me how to markup a menu that contains multiple icons in your answer?

Comment: Okay, the markup for the menu xml needs to be separate please so it doesn't confuse future visitors, because it is a separate file , Thanks anyway

Comment: Hey the menu show up as a list, I needed icons populated from the right to left my toolbar?

Comment: add 'app:showAsAction="always"' in your menu item

Comment: Okay, trying that in a few

Comment: Same problem, it still shows a menu list and I need icons on the toolbar

Comment: 'android:showAsAction="always"' Try it.